# Is there something similar to a chrome.tabs.onFocused event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a Chrome extension whose icon needs to change whenever a relevant tab becomes active/inactive.

This works fine by relying on the following events:

```
  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(({ tabId }) => {
    updateIcons(tabId)
  })

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId) => {
    updateIcons(tabId)
  })
```

There are some cases, where I am on the relevant tab, and my extension's icon is "active" as expected, but when that page happens to open up a popup (not a modal, but an actual page in a popup), then my extension's icon becomes "inactive". This is also expected and fine.
However, when the user closes that popup-page and the focus is brought back to the original tab, my extension's icon remains "inactive" because none of the above events fires again.

Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: What does your `updateIcons()` function  do? How is a tab's relevance determined? Without more info it's hard to say for sure, but the [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeContent/) may provide the functionality your looking for. Alternatively, you can use [action.setIcon()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-setIcon) and specify a tabId to modify the icon only on a given tab.

Comment: Probably chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.